# Event log - attaching to some event task which will run a program. Can I pass to this program event params?

Tags: windows-event-log, application

I would like to run a program only when a specific ASP.NET event occurs in the event-log. Is there any chance that it will get passed the event details when it is triggered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can schedule a task to occur when something in the Event Log happens. See here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa446887(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: From that I see that it is the script's responsibility to re-query the Event Log for any event-data it needs. It is NOT passed directly to it as an argument.

Comment: I was afraid that passing event variables to program which will be runned when event occur is not possible. So thank you for answering and I'm accepting currently proposed answer.